# Is there any Android flickr open source application?

Tags: android

I am looking for flickr open source android 3.2 application for my learing purpose. If it is there somewhere, please help me out.

Comment: Are you looking for a full-blown app or will an API with samples do too? I haven't used [FlickrJ Android](http://code.google.com/p/flickrj-android/) (yet), but it looks quite promising. It comes with a [short guide](http://code.google.com/p/flickrj-android/wiki/HowToGuide4Android) and some [sample code](http://code.google.com/p/flickrj-android/source/browse/) that should offer a good starting point on the subject matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find a good sample [here](http://flickr-viewer-for-honeycomb.googlecode.com)